# SyntaxError in webpack.config.js preventing webpack from running

Tags: webpack

For the life of me I cannot see why it is giving this error.

webpack.config.js:

```
{
  context: __dirname + "/Content/src",
  entry: "./app",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: __dirname + "/Content/src",
        loader: "babel",
        query: {
          optional: ["es7.decorators"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The error message I get when I run webpack is

```
...\webpack.config.js:3
  entry: "./app",
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at module.exports (C:\path\to\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:80:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\path\to\webpack\bin\webpack.js:39:40)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
```

I tried moving around some of the fields and what not but it continuously throws a SyntaxError at a colon. Always one of the first couple fields. I've tried just running it all from the command line directly but I get a different error there that I would have to figure out. This seems easier.

I haven't tried the node api but this is supposed to be a proof of concept type thing and I don't want to set up gulp to try and use the webpack api when I really feel this should suffice.

My project is using webpack version 1.12.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webpack.config.js is simply an invalid JavaScript file.

You have attempted to create an object literal with your configuration options in, but you have not declared a variable to assign it to, nor exported it as a value.

The fix should therefore be very simple:

Add `module.exports =` before your opening `{` and this will export the config object from the file for webpack to consume.

Comment: I feel pretty dumb. I just copy and pasted from their website. The basic one did not include the module.exports bit. Thank you!